# How to cross thread calls in native C++ (call back on main thread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, cross-thread

I am implementing the C++ mobile apps to call some process which taking some times to make it done, but I need my apps main thread is still running without any blocking.

Question: 
Is there any library that could just call runOnUIThread to get back the result on main thread?

*Understand that there a lot of answer such as message event queue polling to get back the result on main thread, or using future/promise to keep looping the result. But I don't want these kind of solution to achieve the target.*

I believe in C++ way has some function to get back main thread looper and call the function with multiple entry point to main thread? I have red this article, I'm not really understand what it means, hope someone could help.

[Cross Thread Call in native C++](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16726/Cross-thread-calls-in-native-C)

Comment: *"Understand that there a lot of answer such as message event queue polling to get back the result on main thread, or using future/promise to keep looping the result. But I don't want these kind of solution."* - in other words you know the solutions available but choose not to use them for unspecified reasons.  Voting to close.

Comment: I read this question and I don't get it. Are you asking how to pass messages between threads? Also the phrase `Is there any library that could just call runOnUIThread to get back the result on main thread?` is unintelligible.

Comment: @Mikhail Not passing message between threads, But signal other thread function. For example, Thread A has all the data been initialized, but Thread B has nothing just process a small scope of function, how you can get back the result from Thread B? So far I know the only way is polling a object which is shared between threads. But not everyone can understand or how to poll it. I want to build a simple way.

Comment: @Oktaheta Threads are notified through condition variables.  Start with `std::condition_variable` or `QWaitCondition`.

Comment: @Mikhail GUI thread cannot block, so i can't use this condition.

Comment: @Oktaheta You're supposed to spin up another thread to process the work.. Look up the example for Qt's `QWaitCondition` its similar to the standard producer consumer queue.

Answer (score -1):

C++ as a language does not have a standard way of doing cross thread messaging. This means you need to implement your own solution that depends on the frameworks you are using.